# mysql, grouping values that are different

Tags: mysql

Say i have the follow values,

```
1, a, 10
2, a, 20,
3, a, 30,
4, a, 1,
5, a, 2,
6, a, 30
7, a, 30
```

how can i make a query so that i can get the SUM of all **DIFFERENT** values?

i want the output to be: `63`
it excluded values 6,7

in my real scenario i was using:

```
SELECT *, SUM(DISTINCT(exp)) / 1000000000 as bil from player_attributes
where date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
group by player
order by bil
```

with no luck.

Comment: why exclude 6,7 and not 3? any other conditions

Answer (score 0):

suppose your table structure = tab [id, a, exp]

```
SELECT tab.a, sum(tab.exp)
FROM tab, (
    SELECT exp,min(id) mid 
    FROM tab
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY 1
) AS tab_a
WHERE tab.id=tab_a.mid
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DistinctSum=sum(distinct x) / 1000000000 as bil
from
(
    SELECT X=value FROM  player_attributes
    where date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
) x
```

Try this ... think so it is useful fot you...